# Selecting an element that includes a certain string in ID by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the element I am trying to select:

```
<div id="RadDataForm1_ctrl0_listCountryDestination" class="RadListBox RadListBox_Default rlbFixedHeight" style="height:200px;width:225px;">
```

My jQuery code:

```
var listbox = $("*[id*='listCountryDestination']");
```

It doesn't select the element. Any ideas?

**UPDATE (10/3):**

Here is the error:
[image]

If I use the line below, it finds the element. However, I can't rely on this static string.

```
var listbox = $find('RadDataForm1_ctrl0_listCountryDestination');
```

Comment: No problem. It work. https://jsfiddle.net/kcLja75x/

Comment: The first asterisk isn't necessary

Comment: probably searching for it before it exists

Comment: Are you sure you have jquery loaded correctly?

Comment: @charlietfl it works if I use the full ID at the same line

Comment: @Dekel yes jquery is loaded. Otherwise, $find wouldn't work

Comment: no reason that line would throw error itself. If jQuery can't find matching selector it fails quietly. Need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Well, that's a different question - what exactly is `$find`?

Comment: Are you waiting DOM load to check the node selection? I suggest you to wait load and check the expression directly in your browser console, you'll take it if it's a load issue. You can check your ID in runtime, frameworks like Microsoft WebForms changes the element ID sending a prefix to it.